# Export table on .asp page to excel

Tags: html, asp-classic, export-to-excel

I've been looking on a lot of external links and questions over here but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have a table (coded and made in HTML) on my .asp page(classic ASP). How to i export that onto excel using a button on that page?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx OR http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732232/Export-to-Excel-in-ASP-NET-Csharp

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi: note that both of those are for ASP.net. ASP.net and classic ASP are about as similar as JavaScript and Java, which is to say their names share a syllable or two and they serve a similar purpose. In particular, code written for and working on ASP.net will not work on classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

One Example...

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
response.Buffer = true
Response.Expires = -1
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1 
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache" 
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private" 
Response.CacheControl = "Private" 

'On Error Resume Next
dim sql, rsDadosRel, i, contador, corlinha, cd_ambiente

RESPONSE.CHARSET="UTF-8"

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" 
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment;filename=aasir.xls"


%>
<!--#include file="inc/comum.asp"-->
<!--#include file="inc/funcoes.asp"-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Logs</title>                 
</head>
<body>

    <table border="0" height=44 style="color:#666667;font-size:12px;margin-top:10px;width:auto;" cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 ID="Table1">

                                <%
                                    cd_ambiente = request("cd_ambiente")
                                    sql = " EXEC SPR_LOG_ACCESS 100, '"&cd_ambiente&"', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  NULL, NULL "

                                    'RESPONSE.WRITE SQL
                                    'RESPONSE.END

                                    AbreConexao

                                    SET rsDadosRel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                                    rsDadosRel.CursorLocation = 3

                                    rsDadosRel.Open sql, Conn

                                    if(not rsDadosRel.eof)then

                                            response.write "<tr style=""background-color:#fff;height:40px;"">"

                                            for i = 0 to rsDadosRel.fields.Count - 1 
                                                            response.write "<th style=""text-align:center;border:1px solid #cccccc;background-color:#<%=color;"">" 
                                                            response.write rsDadosRel.fields(i).name 
                                                            response.write "</th>" 
                                            next  
                                            Response.Write "  </tr>"
                                            while not rsDadosRel.eof
                                                response.write "<tr>" 
                                                contador = contador + 1
                                                if contador mod 2 = 0 then corlinha = "f1f1f1" else corlinha = "e0e0e0"
                                                    'Response.Write corlinha
                                                    for i = 0 to rsDadosRel.fields.Count - 1 
                                                        response.write "<td style=""width:5%; text-align:center;border:1px solid #c0c0c0;background-color:#"&corlinha&""">" & (rsDadosRel.fields(i)) & "</td>" 
                                                    next
                                                rsDadosRel.MoveNext
                                                response.flush
                                            wend
                                    else
                                %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:left;border:1px solid #cccccc;" colspan="13"><b>Não existe nenhuma solicitação para esta pesquisa!</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <%      
                                    end if
                                %>

    </table>   
</body>
</html>
    <%
    'response.write err.number
    'response.end
    if err.number <> 0 then
        response.clear
        Dim objError
        Set objError = Server.GetLastError()

        %>

            <h2 align="center">Error</h2>

            <p align="center">An error occurred processing the page that you requested.<br>
            Please see the error details below for more information.</p>

            <div align="center"><center>

            <table width="700px">
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">Desc Error </th>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                <%
                    Response.Write "An Error Has Occurred on this page!<BR>"
                    Response.Write "The Error Number is: " & Err.number & "<BR>"
                    Response.Write "The Description given is: " & Err.Description & "<BR>"
                %>
                </td>
              </tr>


            <% If Len(CStr(objError.ASPCode)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">IIS Error Number</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.ASPCode%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.Number)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">COM Error Number</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.Number%>
                <%=" (0x" & Hex(objError.Number) & ")"%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.Source)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">Error Source</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.Source%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.File)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">File Name</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.File%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.Line)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">Line Number</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.Line%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.Description)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">Brief Description</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.Description%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            <% If Len(CStr(objError.ASPDescription)) > 0 Then %>
              <tr>
                <th nowrap align="left" valign="top">Full Description</th>
                <td align="left" valign="top"><%=objError.ASPDescription%></td>
              </tr>
            <% End If %>
            </table>

            </center></div>

        <%

        response.end
    end if

    %>

<%
FechaConexao
%>
```